# pd.json_normalize() gives “str object has no attribute 'values'"

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I manually create a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df_articles1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id'   : [4,5,8,9],
                            'Class':[
                                        {'encourage': 1, 'contacting': 1},
                                        {'cardinality': 16, 'subClassOf': 3},
                                        {'get-13.5.1': 1},
                                        {'cardinality': 12, 'encourage': 1}
                                    ]
                            })
```

I export it to a csv file to import after splitting it:

```
df_articles1.to_csv(f"""{path}articles_split.csv""", index = False, sep=";")
```

I can split it with `pd.json_normalize()`:

```
df_articles1 = pd.json_normalize(df_articles1['Class'])
```

I import its csv file to a DataFrame:

```
df_articles2 = pd.read_csv(f"""{path}articles_split.csv""", sep=";")
```

But this fails with:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' pd.json_normalize(df_articles2['Class'])

Comment: that was because when you save by `to_csv()` the data in your **class** column is stored as `string` not as `dictionary/json`

Comment: df_articles1.dtypes returns "object" type for Class column. It should return string?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code you posted runs without error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the accepted answer works, **[using `eval` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/13138364).**

To parse a string column that *looks* like JSON/dict, use one of the following options (last one is best, if possible).

---

#### [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (better)

```
import ast

objects = df2['Class'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
normed = pd.json_normalize(objects)
df2[['Id']].join(normed)

#    Id  encourage  contacting  cardinality  subClassOf  get-13.5.1
# 0   4        1.0         1.0          NaN         NaN         NaN
# 1   5        NaN         NaN         16.0         3.0         NaN
# 2   8        NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN         1.0
# 3   9        1.0         NaN         12.0         NaN         NaN
```

---

#### [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) (even better)

```
import json

objects = df2['Class'].apply(json.loads)
normed = pd.json_normalize(objects)
df2[['Id']].join(normed)

#    encourage  contacting  cardinality  subClassOf  get-13.5.1
# 0        1.0         1.0          NaN         NaN         NaN
# 1        NaN         NaN         16.0         3.0         NaN
# 2        NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN         1.0
# 3        1.0         NaN         12.0         NaN         NaN
```

If the strings are single quoted, use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to convert them to double quotes (and thus valid JSON) before applying [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
objects = df2['Class'].str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads)
normed = pd.json_normalize(objects)
df2[['Id']].join(normed)
```

---

#### [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) *before* [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_csv.html) (recommended)

If possible, when you *originally* save to CSV, just save the *normalized* JSON (not raw JSON objects):

```
df1 = df1[['Id']].join(pd.json_normalize(df1['Class']))
df1.to_csv('df1_normalized.csv', index=False, sep=';')

# Id;encourage;contacting;cardinality;subClassOf;get-13.5.1
# 4;1.0;1.0;;;
# 5;;;16.0;3.0;
# 8;;;;;1.0
# 9;1.0;;12.0;;
```

This is a more natural CSV workflow (rather than storing/loading object blobs):

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('df1_normalized.csv', sep=';')

#    Id  encourage  contacting  cardinality  subClassOf  get-13.5.1
# 0   4        1.0         1.0          NaN         NaN         NaN
# 1   5        NaN         NaN         16.0         3.0         NaN
# 2   8        NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN         1.0
# 3   9        1.0         NaN         12.0         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 9):

that was because when you save by `to_csv()` the data in your **'Class'** column is stored as `string` not as `dictionary/json` so after loading that saved data:

```
df_articles2 = pd.read_csv(f"""{path}articles_split.csv""", sep=";")
```

Then  to make it back in original form make use of `eval()` method and `apply()` method:-

```
df_articles2['Class']=df_articles2['Class'].map(eval)
```

Finally:

```
resultdf=pd.json_normalize(df_articles2['Class'])
```

Now If you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output

**Note:** yeah according to **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/13138364).** it's bad to use eval but in some case when you have messedup data you have only option left: that is to use `eval`